# The composition of a dissipative operator and a positive opeartor is dissipative?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let the real Hilbert space $H^1(\Omega)$  endowed with
                its usual inner product, denoted by $\langle ., . \rangle$

and let $A : H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ be a dissipative operator ($\langle A y,y\rangle\leq 0, \; \forall y\in H^1(\Omega)$)

and $B : H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ be a positive operator ($\langle B y,y\rangle\geq 0, \; \forall y\in H^1(\Omega)$).

Can we say that $BA$ is dissipative in other words ($\langle BA y,y\rangle\leq 0, \; \forall y\in H^1(\Omega)$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For a finite dimensional example let $H = \mathbb{R}^2$ and take

$$ A = - B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \tag{exa}$$

For every $y$ you have $\langle Ay,y\rangle = 0 = \langle By,y\rangle$ so both are dissipative. But $AB = BA = I$.

---

For higher dimensions just take a two dimensional subspace, and let $A, B$ act trivially on the rest.

---

Even if you require strict inequality the statement is not true. Replace the $0$ in (exa) above by $-\epsilon$, and you have $A$ is strictly dissipative, $B$ is strictly positive, and $BA = I + O(\epsilon)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Precisely, $A : D(A) \subset H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H^1(\Omega)$ is a linear operator with domain $D(A)$ and generates a semigroup of contractions (so that $A$ is dissipative), and $B=\nabla^*\nabla$ (which is positive) where $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
     \nabla :& H^1(\Omega) & \longrightarrow &(L^2(\Omega))^n\\
     & y & \longmapsto   &  (\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_1},
     \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_2}, ..., \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x_n})
     \end{array}$$ and $\nabla^*$ the adjoint operator. In this case can we say that $BA$ is dissipative.

Comment: You still need some assumptions on $A$. For example, let $0 < \lambda_1 < \lambda_2$ be two eigenvalues of $B$ and $f_1, f_2$ two corresponding eigenfunctions. If you take $Af_1 = f_2$ and $Af_2 = - f_1$, and extend by zero otherwise, $A$ is dissipative. But $$\langle BA(f_1 + f_2), f_1 + f_2\rangle = \langle \lambda_2 f_2 - \lambda_1 f_1, f_1 + f_2\rangle = \lambda_2 - \lambda_1 > 0$$ You can add to $A$ something like $-\epsilon I$ to make it generate a contractive semigroup, but the answer remains more or less the same.

Comment: If you don't want non-self-adjoint operators: take $\Omega$ to be, say, $(-1,1)$. And let $A$ be the multiplication operator $f \mapsto - (x^2  + 1) f$. It is clear that $A$ generates a semigroup of contractions (it acts pointwise!) and that $A$ is self-adjoint. However, let $f$ be the constant function $f \equiv 1$. Then $BA f = - \partial^2_x (- (x^2 + 1)) = 2$ and so $\langle BA f, f\rangle > 0$.

Comment: Consider the following bilinear system
     \begin{equation}
     \left\{\begin{array}{r c l}
     \displaystyle\frac{dy(t)}{dt} &=& Ay(t)+u(t)Cy(t)\\
     y(0) &=& y_0
     \end{array}
     \right.
     \end{equation}
where the state space is $ H^1(\Omega)$  endowed with its usual inner product, denoted by $\langle ., . \rangle$ and  $\|.\|$ the associated norm, the operator $A$ generates   a semigroup of contractions $S(t)$ on $H^1(\Omega)$,   $u(t)$ is a scalar valued control and  $C$ is a linear and bounded  operator mapping $H^1(\Omega)$ into itself.

Comment: Suppose that this system admits a unique mild solution $y$.
Since $A$ generates a semigroup of contractions then from  Lumer-Phillips Theorem $A$ is dissipative ($\langle Ay,y\rangle \leq 0$),
moreover we have $B = \nabla^*\nabla$ is positive ($\langle By,y\rangle = \langle \nabla y,\nabla y\rangle = \|\nabla y\|^2_{(L^2(\Omega))^n} \geq 0$).

So in this case, are there some assumptions to add in order  to get $\langle BAy,y\rangle \leq 0$?

Comment: A sufficient condition (I think; don't quote me on this) would be if $A$ is self-adjoint and $[A,B] = 0$; and if you are lucky you may be able to get away with the case where $[A,B]$ is "suitably small"; at least both are true in finite dimensions. For densely defined unbounded operators there may be some caveats. It may be worth asking on MathOverflow; I think the question as you have written in the previous two comments are precise enough.